# firebase - Firebase Current User not storing the correct user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, local-storage, firebase-authentication

I have a project using Firebase for the authentication. When I log into my project, sometimes the `firebase.auth().currentUser` method returns info from some other user. Sometimes I get the info from the actual current user and sometimes the previously signed in user - when this happens, the only way to correct the problem and get data for the correct user is to logout and sign back in again.

My login method:

```
onLoginClick = () => {
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email.trim(), this.state.password.trim())
    .then((user) => {
        //Some redirects depending on my users role
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, error.message);
        if (error.code == "auth/user-not-found" || error.code == "auth/wrong-password") {
            //Handle error
        }
    });
```

}

And my Logout method:

```
onLogoutClick = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
        this.props.history.replace("/")
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

They're pretty standard but seems like I'm doing something wrong. I've tried clearing the `sessionStorage` and the `localStorage` on the logout method but that didn't help.

UPDATE:

I've tried with some suggestions like doing:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
        //My redirects and everything
    })
})
```

But this doesn't work.

Also, I've noticed that when I log in and use wrong credentials, the sessionStorage gets an entry with the previously signed in user, even though I signed him out.

Comment: Before you login check if the current user is nil. if it's not call your sign out function then sign the user in. Most likely this is happening because the old user is still signed in. How are you exiting the app? Does the user stay signed in?

Comment: @DoesData When I logout the user it; redirects my app to the home screen, all the signed in user options dissapear and I checked the developers console and the localStorage seems like it doesn't have the currentUser key. But then, when I Log in again, even though I checked before, sometimes gets the info wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that during the initialization of a new login session, until it is complete, `currentUser` hasn't been updated yet; use the `user` *parameter* when one is passed in on those methods.  Because the login is still *in progress*, there is not yet a `currentUser`, so it passes the user in progress via the `user` parameter.  (I think this means it is likely that it will be `null` the first time someone logs in, and it will be the previous one thereafter, unless it's cleared on logout by some code.)

Use the `user` parameter when it is provided, such as in the `onAuthStateChanged` handler.  See the first example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users), and the starred note in the blue box farther down that same page.

Comment: I am using the `firebase.auth().currentUser` in the next screen, which is accessed only after the login was successfull and has finished

Comment: The question and the code excerpts don't actually show how `currentUser` is being used (it doesn't appear at all), so I'm only able to speculate based on the common problems in this area. Is a more complete sample of the code available anywhere? Can you reproduce the problem with a fairly simple bit of example code?  And I guess the final question is if you're using `firebase.auth().currentUser` directly (vs. saving it via variables, etc.) or if that is just shorthand/pseudocode for what you're doing in more complex code.

Comment: After the login I redirect to another component (I'm using ReactJS), in which I need to query the user node to retrieve some info about the user. An example of the query I'm trying to do is `firebase.database().ref('notifications/pending/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + key)
                            .once('value')
                            .then(notifications => {
                                //setSate the number of notifications
                            });`

Comment: I think the question is what "after the login" means, i.e. the context for these calls. If it's called directly or indirectly from `signInWithEmailAndPassword().then` I'm not sure the currentUser field is updated yet. The calling code might do that. If you're satisfied with the auth, you could always try a kludge to assign `user` to `currentUser`, as a test.

Comment: I've removed my misleading (signInWithRedirect) comment. Ignore that. If you're in `then` code from the `signIn`, you may need to pass the `user` parameter through to whatever you're calling. I think the problem here is that it's just too early to reference `currentUser` yet from the `then` of a `signIn`.

Comment: It's not on the then of the sign in. In the `then()` callback of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` I use the parameter user to get the `uid`, fetch the user's role and then redirect to the appropriate view, After the redirect, on the `componentDidMount()` of the next component (i.e. the appropriate view) I call the `firebase.auth().currentUser`, in the query I specified before. I think it's not a race condition problem because before the respective view is loaded, the `localStorage` already has a `key`:'value` pair created by Firebase.